# Books exploring economics of Leisure and free time?

Tags: reference-request, workforce

One I found already is "Finding Time: The Economics of Work-Life Conflict" by Boushey, what are some other books I could read about this topic?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the ["Handbook on the Economics of Leisure"](https://ideas.repec.org/b/elg/eebook/13469.html) would be a good starting point for you.

> This interdisciplinary Handbook combines both mainstream and heterodox
> economics to assess the nature, scope and importance of leisure
> activity. Surprisingly, the field of leisure economics is not, thus
> far, a particularly integrated or coherent one. In this Handbook a
> wide ranging body of international scholars get to grips with this
> issue, taking in the traditional income/leisure choice model of
> textbook microeconomics and Becker's allocation of time model along
> the way. They expertly apply economics to some usually neglected
> topics, such as boredom, sleeping and social networking which
> encourages a move towards an integrate field of economics of leisure.
> Contributions from further afield by Veblen, Sctivosky and Bourdieu
> also feature prominently.

Applying a mix of theoretical and empirical work, it is a nice read for undergraduates as well as general public interested in Economics.

---

Samuel Cameron (ed.), 2011. "Handbook on the Economics of Leisure," Books, Edward Elgar Publishing, number 13469.